# Can't pickle matplotlib figure: error "Can't pickle 'tkapp' object"

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pickle

I'm trying to save a matplotlib.pyplot figure using `Pickle`.

However, I get the following error:

```
`pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle 'tkapp' object: <tkapp object at 0x061047B8>
```

I've read some other posts regarding problems with Pickle, but I've not been able to resolve my issue.

Please note I'm using `python 2.7.11` and `Matplotlib 1.5.1`.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import imread
import pickle

plt.figure()
plt.pot(x,y,label='one')
ax = plt.gca()
img = imread('C:/theview.jpg')
ax.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
ax.invert_yaxis()
legend = plt.legend(numpoints=1)
legend.draggable()
pickle.dump(ax, file(saveFigureAs,'wb')
```

Comment: The error means just what it says - the object is not able to be pickled. That happens...

Comment: I realize that, and I would like to know why the object is not able to be pickled.  It seems to have something to do with use `plot` and `imshow` together.  If I just use `imshow` it will pickle.  If I just use `plot` it will pickle.  If I use both, it doesn't pickle.